# InfluxDB where query on tag values

Tags: influxdb, influxql

I am trying to write a where clause on InfluxDB where the points are filtered via their *key values*.

My points have the field `ping_to_google.com` and the tag key `user` where user can be `raspi-2` or `raspi-5`. This is a sample output of the database:

```
> select * from networks where time > now()-1h
name: networks
time                 ping_to_google.com user
----                 ------------------ ----
1645494054000000000  3.528              raspi-2
1645494078000000000  3.578              raspi-2
```

I am using InfluxDB version 1.8 and InfluxDB shell version 1.6.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will work!

```
select * from networks where time > now()-1h AND "user"='raspi-2'
```

According to the [documentation](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/query_language/explore-data/#tags) of the influxDB you should only single qoute tag values:

**Tags**

`tag_key <operator> ['tag_value']`

Single quote tag values in the WHERE clause. Queries with unquoted tag values or double quoted tag values will not return any data and, in most cases, will not return an error.

They don't specify how to write tag keys. It is crazy that the database does not produce any errors in most cases. Also, it's not clear (and very unexpected after reading this documentation) that the tag key should be double-qouted. But this works and is how to do it!